# Value of the following series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

What is the value of

$ 1.2/(3!) + (2.(2)^2)/(4!) + (3.(2)^3)/(5!).........+(15.(2)^{15})/(17!)$

$a.)$ $ 2-16.2^{17}/17! $

$b.)$ $ 2-2^{17}/17! $

$c.)$ $ 1-16.2^{17}/17! $

$d.)$ $ 1-2^{16}/17! $

My attempt: I tried to find out if I could make partial fractions of the general term of the given series . However to no avail as because of the presence of the $2^n$ and the factorial term , each term would come out with a different coefficient thus they cancel each other once the series was expanded. 
Please tell me if there is a better way , or inform me on how to make correct partial fractions ?

Comment: Your last term should be $2^{15}$ not $2^15$ - you need $\{\}$ around the 15. Also putting parentheses round the 2s makes it less clear, not more clear.

Comment: Yep corrected that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\frac{k 2^k}{(k+2)!}+\frac{2^{k+1}}{(k+2)!}=\frac{2^k}{(k+1)!}$

So if we add $\frac{2^{16}}{17!}$ to the sum at the end, then it collapses down.